# CASE WHEN for changing duplicate value

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, case, data-manipulation

I am trying to add a case when statement which would add +1day into a date column of a record, if there are duplicates per two columns.

This would be the original table:

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Red | Table | 2023-01-01 |
| Red | Table | 2023-01-01 |

This would be the result:

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Red | Table | 2023-01-01 |
| Red | Table | 2023-01-02 |

I know using DATEADD would be enough to update the date
`select DATEADD( 'day',1,'2023-09-13')::date;` but having trouble understanding how to grab the duplicate fields and only update one of them inside a case when statement during column selection.

EDIT: If column A & B are identical, I want the second records C columns to be updated with +1 day.

```
CASE    
        WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a,b > 1) 
            THEN DATEADD('day', 1, a)
        ELSE a
        END AS c
```

Something like this would update both rows for example.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: What defines a record as being duplicate?

Comment: You should be able to distinguish between the two by including the primary key, which probably should be a surrogate key.  If this is a truly duplicate record (no difference between any columns) then there is no primary key.  Maybe fire your data modeler and start over?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I've updated the question, but it would be identical records in column A & B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were on the right track.  You should be using the result from `ROW_NUMBER` minus one as the number of days to add to the date:

```sql
SELECT *, DATEADD(
              'day',
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY A, B ORDER BY C) - 1,
              C) AS new_date
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY 1, 2, 3;
```

To address your follow up question, where you only want to increase the date when some column `D` does not match a certain value, you could use:

```
DATEADD(
    'day',
    COUNT(CASE WHEN D != 123 THEN 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY A, B ORDER BY C) - 1,
    C)
```

Comment: This is excactly what I am looking for thanks! Is there any way to enforce a check on an addition column, say that would make sure column D != D for these records?

Comment: Yes, add a `WHERE` clause after `FROM`, e.g. `WHERE D != <some value>`

Comment: What about inside the case statement? To still include these rows, but if column D between the duplicated doesn't match, only update then.